# Time complexity of ArrayList Insertion : Calculating sum of X + X/2 + X/4 + X/8 + ... 1

Tags: time-complexity

Here is an excerpt from Cracking Coding Interview book where it's talking about the time complexity of insertion to an ArrayList.

[image]

I am trying to prove that the sum of $X + \frac{X}{2} + \frac{X}{4} + \frac{X}{8} + .... 1 $ is $2X$.

Given,

\begin{align}
 & X + \frac{X}{2} + \frac{X}{4} + \frac{X}{8} + .... 1 \\
 & = X (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + .... \frac{1}{X}) \\ 
 & = 2^n (\frac{1}{2^0} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + .... \frac{1}{2^n}) \\
& = 2^n * S_{n+1}
\end{align}

Here, $S_{n+1}$ is the sum upto $n+1$ elements,

\begin{align}
 S_{n+1} & =  \frac{1}{2^0} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + .... \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \frac{1}{2^n} \\
 S_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2^n} & = \frac{1}{2^0} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + .... \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \\
 S_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2^n} & = S_n
\end{align}

Also,
\begin{align}
 S_{n+1} & =  \frac{1}{2^0} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + .... \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \frac{1}{2^n} \\
 2S_{n+1} & = 2 + \frac{1}{2^0} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + .... \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \\
2S_{n+1} & = 2 + S_n \\
2S_{n+1} -2 & = S_n \\
\end{align}

Now combining both,
\begin{align}
 S_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2^n} &= 2S_{n+1} -2 \\
S_{n+1} &= 2 - \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align}

As n approaches infinity, $S_{n+1} = 2$

This is as far as I've gotten. I am wondering how to continue from here. Also, am I in the right path?

---

15 minutes later here is what I've figured out.

Placing the value of $S_{n+1}$ back to the original expression,

\begin{align}
 & X + \frac{X}{2} + \frac{X}{4} + \frac{X}{8} + .... 1 \\
 & = X (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + .... \frac{1}{X}) \\ 
 & = 2^n (\frac{1}{2^0} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + .... \frac{1}{2^n}) \\
& = 2^n * S_{n+1} \\
& = 2^n (2 - \frac{1}{2^n})\\
& = 2^n * 2 - 1\\
& = 2X - 1\\
& \approx 2X \\
\end{align}

But I am not sure if it's correct. I've appreciated some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take main phrase from your book:

"If you read this sum left to right, it starts with 1 and doubles until it gets to $X$"

This means, that $X=2^k$, for some $k$. So, simply using [geometrical progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), we have
$$1+2+4+\cdots+2^k=\frac{X}{2^k} +\frac{X}{2^{k-1}} + \cdots+\frac{X}{2^2}+\frac{X}{2}+ X = \frac{1-2^{k+1}}{1-2}=2^{k+1}-1=2X-1$$

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was simpler than what I was doing!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use induction.

Here is a rough outline of a proof I would create:

- X + X/2 + X/4 + X/8 + ... 1 = 2X - 1 is equivalent to 2^k + 2^(k-1) +
  ... 2^1 + 2^0 = 2*2^k - 1 for all X=2^k
- Let us create a proposition P(k) which is that: 2^k + 2^(k-1) + ...
  2^1 + 2^0 = 2*2^k - 1
- P(0) is true as 2^0 = 2 * 2^0 - 1
- Let us assume that P(k) is true. P(k+1) is whether 2^(k+1) + 2^k + ...
  2^1 + 2^0 = 2*2^(k+1) - 1
- 2^(k+1) + 2^k + ... 2^1 + 2^0 = 2^(k+1) + 2*2^k - 1 (Using the fact that P(k) is true)
- 2^(k+1) + 2*2^k - 1 = 2^(k+1) + 2^(k+1) - 1 = 2*2^(k+1) - 1
- Hence P(k) implies that P(k+1)
- Hence, by induction P(k) holds for all natural numbers k.
- Hence, X + X/2 + X/4 + X/8 + ... 1 = 2X - 1 ≈ 2X.